# How to I map "Ctrl + g" to open NerdTree

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I use vim at work, but we have an IT guy who installed a bunch of magical plugins for vim on my work laptop so that now when I try to open `vim` on my home laptop, I am completely lost because I don't have any shortcuts or key mappings.

I just installed NerdTree. I don't want to have to type `:NERDTree` everytime I want to open it. How would I map "Ctrl + g" to open and close NERDTree? Where would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mappings work just like a recorded sequence of keys (as the right-hand side). As this is Vim, you need to be aware of the *modes*; here, *normal mode*, so `n`:

```
:nnoremap <C-g> :NERDTree<CR>
```

This maps (without remapping, the `nore...` part) to `<C-g>` (see `:help key-notation`) the `:NERDTree` command, concluded by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To have this permanently, put the line into your user's `~/.vimrc`.